# Chrome service worker doesn't update after displaying push messages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, dom-events, service-worker

I've created a serviceworker to display push notifications.
When I change the `serviceworker.js` file and navigate to the page that updates it, I can see that the service worker was updated.
But once a push message is displayed, the service worker can only be updated after the Chrome browser is closed.

I am using this:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    self.skipWaiting();
});
```

…but it doesn’t seem to help.

Comment: Updating the code of a service worker can be tricky. Check out [this post](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2017/05/update-the-service-worker-and-the-scripts-imported-with-importscripts/). Also, you can [check the version of the service worker](http://blog.pushpad.xyz/2017/05/inspect-service-workers-with-chrome/) that is currently installed by using the Chrome developer tools.

Comment: I've kind of solved it by unregistering the service and then re-regestering it.

Comment: You can just register it again (without unregistering).

Comment: registering without unregister didn't work. the new service-worker was added to the stack and would only take over after browser restart.

Comment: Yes, exactly: the update is completed after the browser restart (or after all tabs for that domain are closed).

Comment: well, thats exactly what I didn't want to happen!